# Rethinkdb connection with cloudflare

Tags: nginx, rethinkdb, cloudflare

I am running Rethinkdb on a server that lays behind cloudflare. I cannot make connection with my server when using my hostname. (I can access other stuff on my server so i am almost sure the problem doesn't lies there)
I am also able to connect using my ip directly (without adding a cert to the .connect function of rethinkdb client)

I do use Nginx and my client is in java

What i have tried:

- Using custom set ports (that were said to be open on cloudflare)
- trying proxying location to certain port
- Using a cert (Rethink client side)

I couldn't find any information about Rethinkdb behind CloudFlare, so i am open to any suggestions

If i need to post more information please ask, i'm not sure what i should share...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a RethinkDB issue. Cloudflare only supports specific ports, as spelled out here:

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-Cloudflare-work-with-

```
80
8080
8880
2052
2082
2086
2095
```

And all traffic must be HTTP sessions. RethinkDB communicates via raw TCP sockets. You cannot run it behind Cloudflare.

Comment: I found the open sockets on in an other post but didn't see anywhere that the connections where different. 
I ended up making another A record with only dns activated (grey cloud) and using that one for connections
thanks for your answer :)